# solving the inequalty

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials

are there any ways to solve :$ x^4 -6x^3 +28x^2 -64x +96 >0$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some identities that immediately yield the result ;D $$x^4 - 6x^3 + 28x^2 - 64x + 96 = 16(x - 2)^2 + x^2(x - 3)^2 + 3x^2 + 32 > 32 > 0$$ and the other even better identity that can be used is $$x^4 - 6x^3 + 28x^2 - 64x + 96 = \big((x - 2)^2 + 4\big) \cdot \big((x - 1)^2 + 11\big) > 4 \cdot 11 = 44 > 0$$

Comment: nice approach, many thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since the whole curve lies above $y=0$, the solution is: for all $x$ (or more formal: $x\in\mathbb{R}$).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way is to look at the derivative $$y=x^4 -6x^3 +28x^2 -64x +96$$ $$y'=4 x^3-18 x^2+56 x-64$$ If you know the way to solve cubic equations, you would find that the derivative has only one real root and two conjugate complex roots. The real root is given by $$ \frac{1}{2} \left(3+\frac{\sqrt[3]{63+4 \sqrt{4821}}}{3^{2/3}}-\frac{29}{\sqrt[3]{3
   \left(63+4 \sqrt{4821}\right)}}\right) \simeq 1.73948$$ For this value $y=46.971$ and the second derivative test shows that this is a minimum. So the inequality holds for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I dont unfourtenaly

Comment: In such a case, I think that a plot of the function gives you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way - clearly, for negative $x$, each term of the LHS is positive, so the inequality is trivial.  So we need to consider only $x > 0$.  Now write the LHS as
$$(x^4-6x^3+9x^2)+(19x^2-64x+96)$$

Note by AM-GM, $x^4+9x^2 \ge 6x^3$ and $19x^2+96 \ge 8\sqrt{114}\;x > 64x$.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, whenever dealing with such problems, always complete the perfect power. Take

a look at the fourth $($well, fifth$)$ row of [Pascal's triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle), containing the [binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) which

result from applying Newton's [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem). Notice that the second coefficient is a $4$, not a $-6$

as is clearly the case here, so, since $-\dfrac64=-\dfrac32$ , what we have to do now is to depress the quartic by subtracting  $\bigg(x-\dfrac32\bigg)^4$ from our original polynomial, thus finally arriving at a quadratic poly- nomial with rational coefficients, $\dfrac{232x^2-808x+1455}{16}$ . Then, by [completing the square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square) in the

numerator, we have $232\bigg(x-\dfrac{101}{58}\bigg)^2+\dfrac{21793}{29}$ . So our polynomial is the sum of three positive

quantities, out of which the first two are always $\ge0$, and the last one is always $>0$. Thus the poly-

nomial is always $>0$.

Answer (score 0):

The function has no real roots, this means that either all values are positive or all values are negative, for $x=0,f(x)=96$ which is a positive value. All values are positive, since any positive value is larger than zero, this means that it's true for all $x$.

Comment: how do you know it has no roots?